# How to prevent ANR if using worker thread?

Tags: android

My app downloads and unzips some data from raw file at first launch. **All long-running processes are performed in service in background thread** so i believe there is no obvious reason for ANR (correct me).

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
        job = extractJob(intent);
        InstallResultSender sender = new InstallResultSender(receiver);

        // add one more receiver
        synchronized (senders) {
            senders.add(sender);
        }

        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new InitThread(job);
            thread.start();
        }

        // no need to restart service or redeliver intent
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

The progress and status messages are sent to activity using android `ResultReceiver`:

```
private ResultReceiver receiver;

public void sendProgress(int percent) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt(InstallResultReceiver.DATA_PROGRESS, percent);
        receiver.send(InstallResultReceiver.RESULT_PROGRESS, data);
    }
```

The activity just shows ProgressDialog and updates percentage and status message.

The problem is that while downloading/installing ANR happens and then Android sends signal 6 (abort). How can i prevent/walk-around this?

ANR reason is amazon in-app purchase billing receiver, but it does not matter i believe.

Log:

```
04-04 13:01:51.016: DEBUG/ActivityInstallListener(1912): on started INSTALL ArmstrongNumber c (1)
04-04 13:01:53.695: DEBUG/ActivityInstallListener(1912): saved repository (9233 bytes)
04-04 13:01:53.695: DEBUG/ActivityInstallListener(1912): on started INSTALL HarmonicNumberSeries c (1)
04-04 13:01:53.885: ERROR/ActivityManager(275): ANR in name.mycompany.android.myapp
        Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY flg=0x10000010 pkg=name.mycompany.android.myapp cmp=name.mycompany.android.myapp/com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.ResponseReceiver (has extras) }
        Load: 6.71 / 6.75 / 3.23
        CPU usage from 0ms to 5942ms later:
        59% 1912/name.mycompany.android.myapp: 50% user + 8.4% kernel / faults: 809 minor
        24% 275/system_server: 18% user + 6.3% kernel / faults: 1131 minor
        4% 29/mmcqd: 0% user + 4% kernel
        0.6% 505/com.android.phone: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 150 minor
        1% 47/adbd: 0% user + 1% kernel
        0% 519/com.amazon.tcomm: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 135 minor
        0% 1715/com.amazon.client.metrics: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 236 minor
        0% 12/pdflush: 0% user + 0% kernel
        0.8% 40/mediaserver: 0.1% user + 0.6% kernel
        0% 552/com.amazon.imp: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 123 minor
        0.1% 909/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 104 minor
        0% 459/com.lab126.softkeybar: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 110 minor
        0% 539/com.android.providers.downloads: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 99 minor
        0.3% 545/android.process.media: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 167 minor
        0% 988/com.nuance.swype.input: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 97 minor
        0.5% 13/kswapd0: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
        0.1% 319/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 20 minor
        0.3% 1343/com.amazon.ags.app: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 174 minor
        0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 85 minor
        0% 1944/com.amazon.mas.test: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 19 minor
        100% TOTAL: 73% user + 25% kernel + 0.1% irq + 0.1% softirq
        CPU usage from 5132ms to 5817ms later:
        62% 1912/name.mycompany.android.myapp: 56% user + 6.4% kernel / faults: 12 minor
        35% 1912/ndroid.myapp: 35% user + 0% kernel
        33% 1957/Thread-208: 22% user + 11% kernel
        1.6% 1919/Compiler: 1.6% user + 0% kernel
        15% 275/system_server: 5.7% user + 10% kernel / faults: 1 minor
        11% 293/ActivityManager: 4.3% user + 7.2% kernel
        13% 29/mmcqd: 0% user + 13% kernel
        0.7% 12/pdflush: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
        1.4% 40/mediaserver: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
        1.4% 40/mediaserver: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
        0.4% 47/adbd: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
        0.4% 47/adbd: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
        100% TOTAL: 62% user + 35% kernel + 1.4% irq
04-04 13:01:53.925: INFO/ActivityManager(275): Tablet:Platform:package=name.mycompany.android.myapp;DV;1,event=app-anr;DV;1:NR
04-04 13:01:53.925: INFO/Process(275): Sending signal. PID: 1912 SIG: 6
```

Comment: post the worker thread code. and check if your operation blocking ui anywhere

Comment: it does not block it as it's service and it does not have access to ui

Comment: 4ntoine but the Service itself is ran in UI thread and has access to UI thread.

Comment: Are you sure you are not holding to long synchronized (senders) { } in you thread? Maybe new request is send to your service, and it is blocked on this synchronized statement (because it is locked in your thread).

Comment: @DoctororDrive. Yes, thread starts in main thread. This is the only thing and it does not affect such result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not publishing the full source code and the reason was in it:
i was handling the results from the service right in `ResultReceiver.onReceiveResult()`. The problem was resolved by using Handler, so i just had to put processing in runnable queue. Also i reduced state saving invocations count after each intent is received (which reduced invocations count on ui thread) and saved it once in the end.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

/**
 *
 */
private class ReceiveResultRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int resultCode;
    private Bundle resultData;

    public ReceiveResultRunnable(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.resultData = resultData;
    }

    public void run() {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_STARTED:
                listener.onStarted();
                break;

            case RESULT_MESSAGE:
                String message = resultData.getString(DATA_MESSAGE);
                listener.onMessage(message);
                break;

            case RESULT_PROGRESS:
                int progress = resultData.getInt(DATA_PROGRESS);
                listener.onProgress(progress);
                break;

            case RESULT_ERROR:
                Throwable t = (Throwable) resultData.getSerializable(DATA_ERROR);
                listener.onError(t);
                break;

            case RESULT_OK:
                int version = resultData.getInt(DATA_REPOSITORY_VERSION);
                listener.onFinished(version);
                break;

            // ...

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onReceiveResult(final int resultCode, final Bundle resultData) {
    super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);

    handler.post(new ReceiveResultRunnable(resultCode, resultData));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html states

`Caution: A services runs in the same process as the application in which it is declared and in the main thread of that application, by default. So, if your service performs intensive or blocking operations while the user interacts with an activity from the same application, the service will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting application performance, you should start a new thread inside the service.`

Furthermore, you can check the state of threads in eclipse by opening the Debug view and seeing the status of your threads.

I'm a little confused as to why you have chosen to use a service over an `AsyncTask` or `IntentService`, which handles creating a non-ui thread for you.

Comment: I think that long task is put in InitThread in the provided code

Comment: You have not provided the implementation of InitThread(job), so no one here is going to be able to help you further

Comment: The service is not stopped on activity recreated so i don't need to pass AsyncTask between rotation states. IntentService processes intents one-by-one (like it's a queue) and it's not what i want

Comment: You can get around this limitation by placing the AsyncTask inside a retained fragment.  http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: thread run() impl is pretty big and it does not matter in my question IMHO as it's doing everything on background thread and does not block main thread. The way it sends results may be improtant, that's why i provided send back result code.

Comment: services are created to do long-running tasks independent of ui so i don't think using AyncTask in retained fragment is good design

Comment: Right but services are explicitly meant for background processing that don't affect the ui, playing music, downloading freely in the background, etc.  whereas in this case you are updating the progress to the ui through various callbacks. In fact if I understand it correctly, you are blocking access to the app until the long running task has finished.  This exact usage case is what AsyncTask's have been designed for

Comment: I'm not blocking UI while the task is performed and you can even finish the app (and return in a minute for example and see progress) but init will be finished in the service

Answer (score 0):

onStartCommand is called in your application's main thread. Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29). Instead, if you use an IntentService, you should override  onHandleIntent (Intent intent), which actually gets called in the worker thread.

Comment: it does exactly the same as my service so there is no need to use IntentService just to avoid ANR